# How do I clean items?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

I have found some Grimy food. I also have heard of a trap that will make my items sticky. Can I clean these items or is the change permanent?

Comment: These are two separate questions, but awnserable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your food become grimy (by having one of your pokémons stepping on a trap), you cannot 'clean' the food. However, it's still edible, albeit at the risk of a random status ailment (so best to do it when you know you can eat the food and then immediatly cure your ailments).

Regarding Sticky Traps, it makes the items you're holding become sticky, and not removeable (if it's an held item). This can happen to both you and your allies. If you're not using any items, a random item will become sticky instead. If an ally steps on the trap and he has no items, nothing will happen. You can 'unstick' items with a Cleanse Orb.

Comment: Do sticky items become un-sticky when you finish the dungeon?

Comment: Yes, any cleanesing effect works. Finishing dungeons and using a cleanse orb should do the trick